# How to delete line which have only number using vim/grep/cat/awk?

Tags: vim, grep, awk, cat

I have this text

```
which will be considered further in Chapter 6
    Siannis et al., 2005
    Crowther and Lambert, 2013a
    Schumacher et al., 1994
    2014
    df=4
    2005
    2005
    0, 1
    4.1
```

I need

```
which will be considered further in Chapter 6
Siannis et al., 2005
Crowther and Lambert, 2013a
Schumacher et al., 1994
df=4
```

I want to delete those lines which have no word. If you can do it using vim/grep/awk/cat or another,welcome.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with grep as follows:

```
$ grep '[a-z]' text.txt
```

Comment: Quote it! Otherwise funny things will happen if you have files whose name is `a`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for words, check for words!

```
$ grep -w '[a-z]\+' file
which will be considered further in Chapter 6
    Siannis et al., 2005
    Crowther and Lambert, 2013a
    Schumacher et al., 1994
    df=4
```

This will print those lines that contain blocks of `[a-z]` characters that are at least 1 character long.